# DataGridView Edit only 1 row in the column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an home work i almost finished it all but i could not get this one 
this is my data grid view columns

```
Name , Price , Quantity , Total , button(to increase) , button (to decrease)
```

in the data Grid View i made a button when i double click on the increase button the quantity will increase by 1 every time 
so i made this code to that

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["Qty"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Add"].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Qty"].Value) + 1;
        }
```

but it do the Entire column if i have 2 rows  when i double click on it the quantity of both rows is increasing 
how can i change that code to just 1 row for the button

Comment: If you think about it, the code is doing exactly what you told it to do.  You have a for each loop, where you go through and 1 to every single quantity.  Instead, you need to filter down the row that was clicked to add one to it.  Try using an index that you encode into each button, and only increase that row number when you click the corresponding button.

Comment: @Bwvolleyball thanks for the help :) 
im still new to this kind of work so i can not get the idea all the time 
thanks for the help again guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over all rows with for statement.

You should use the `CurrentCell.RowIndex` property to get the current selected row.

So you code should look like:

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
row.Cells["Qty"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Add"].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Qty"].Value) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the foreach.
in the button event you need to get the row index.
You can get the row index with

```
 var index = datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Than you can do something like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Qty"].Value = 
Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Add"].Value) 
+ Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Qty"].Value) + 1;
```